# Next/React: Is there a way to only load data once?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using Next for my website. I need to get data from an API and I would like to know if it is possible to only load that data once for my application and only fetch it again if a real reload is made?
I tried to load the data in my _app.js but it is fetched everytime i navigate to another page of my application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your state even if your component unmounted then

These are your options:

Uplift your state : If some ancestor of the component remains mounted then you should maintain your state in that component and pass it on to the component in which you like to use it.

Using some State management : You can also store the state using some state management tool like redux or store it in local storage.